Is there a difference between Monitor On/Off and Desktop/content visible?
I found code in various places that allows my c# program to turn the PC monitors(2) on and off and they work fine (example of the one I am using from MS learning site below).  My object in using the code is to programmatically wake up my PC screen in response to an external event (for which I have a working handler - but which I removed from the test code).
In my control panel (Windows 10) in the "Power & Sleep" section I have the Sleep setting as "Never" and to turn off the monitors after 15 mins of inactivity - which it does.
Hardware is an Intel processor on an ASUS P8Z77-V-LX Motherboard with 16GB memory and 500GB HDD as a system disk.
using System;  
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;  
  
namespace ConsoleApp  
{  
    internal class Program  
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)  
        {  
            const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;  
  
            const uint SC_MONITORPOWER = 0xF170;  
  
            IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);  
  
            // Power off   
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);  
  
            // Power On
            SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, -1);  
        }  
  
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]  
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, uint wParam, int lParam);  
    }  
}

If I simply use the c# test code below it switches my (2) monitors power off and on as advertised, but if the monitors have previously been switched off by Windows (i.e. 15 minutes have elapsed with no activity) my desktop does not reappear - so it's like as if the monitors are on but the PC is not.  When I press any key on the keyboard it all comes back in just a few seconds. Also, when the PC monitors are blanked I can still ping the PC and access it remotely via VNC - so I know it's not shutting down or hibernating.
Clearly, there is some difference between the power control being used by the control panel and the power control which this C# code is toggling - but how can I programmatically access the right one to reawaken the desktop as well as the monitors?

Okay some further testing points the way here....
I tried the code on a different PC with an Intel Motherboard and it works as it should. Clearly my Asus Mobo has some setting or characteristic which is causing my problem.  I will investigate further and post any definite conclusion I come up with.

Okay so I have arrived at a solution, although the underlying cause is still unclear. Sadly Asus were unable to help (I suppose understandably) because the Mobo is no longer a current product.

My Solution:
As per my  post I was using the power settings applet from the control panel to switch off the screen power after n minutes and (significantly) when you go that route the minimum is 2 minutes.
I was playing around with the screen saver settings to see if setting that to "blank" solved my problem, but it did not.  However, during the course of playing with that I noticed that there is a "power settings" link on the bottom of the screensaver applet.  When I clicked on this, I got a different power settings screen - and this one had a 1 minute minimum - so clearly something different.   I cancelled the original "power settings" screen off and used this newly discovered option and it works like I want - my C# code can wake up the display.   I'm not sure why it's different but plainly it is - but only on my ASUS mobo seemingly.
